# Unable to load class Plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to generate first plugin but have this error:
*Could not find implementation class 'CommonPluginClass' for plugin 'common-plugin' specified in jar:file*
*org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'common-plugin']*
[image]
this is my `CommonPluginClass`:

```
class CommonPluginClass: Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.task("hello") {
            doLast {
                println ("Hello from the CommonPluginClass")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

its very simple. My build.gradle (convention)

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        commonPlugin {
            id = "common-plugin"
            implementationClass = "CommonPluginClass"
        }
    }
}
```

and into settings.gradle (build-logic)

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "build-logic"
include(":convention")
```

Into build.gradle (app) i call plugin in this mode:
`plugins { id 'common-plugin' }` 
my exeption:

- What went wrong:
  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'common-plugin']
  Could not find implementation class 'CommonPluginClass.kt' for plugin 'common-plugin' specified in jar:file:/C:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/jars-9/******/convention.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/common-plugin.properties.

  I would like to keep this tree, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In short

You should basically get this to work by changing the `plugins` block of your `build-logic/convention/build.gradle` file to something like the following:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.21'
}
```

### In more detail

I have replicated the relevant bits of your setup as follows (not showing Gradle Wrapper files):

```
├── app
│   └── build.gradle
├── build-logic
│   ├── convention
│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── main
│   │           └── kotlin
│   │               └── CommonPluginClass.kt
│   └── settings.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

The files have the same content as given in your question, except that I’ve changed the files below.

With that, I could successfully run: `./gradlew :app:hello`

##### `build-logic/convention/build.gradle`

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.21'
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        commonPlugin {
            id = "common-plugin"
            implementationClass = "CommonPluginClass"
        }
    }
}
```

##### `build-logic/convention/src/main/kotlin/CommonPluginClass.kt`

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.Plugin

class CommonPluginClass: Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.task("hello") { t ->
            t.doLast {
                println ("Hello from the CommonPluginClass")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### `settings.gradle`

```groovy
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild('build-logic')
}

include ':app'
```

Comment: nothing. you have added `id 'common-plugin'` plugin at *build.gradle:app*. It seems not to build the jar well

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure I understand your comment. Yes, I have (exactly) `plugins { id 'common-plugin' }` in my `app/build.gradle` file. Gradle has also successfully built the plugin jar for me – otherwise running the `:app:hello` task wouldn’t have succeeded. Have you tried any of my changes to your setup? Has that changed anything on your end?

Comment: Yes i have chance my gradles base you code. But i have error again.

Comment: Is it still the same error? How do your `*.gradle` files differ from mine? I’d especially be interested in seeing your top-level `settings.gradle` file. What if you run `./gradlew :build-logic:convention:jar`, does it succeed in creating `build-logic/convention/build/libs/convention.jar`?

Comment: Its success. Updating gradevole version

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it's late

I have faced the same issue and I solved it by moving my plugins folders to the kotlin directory itself and delete the package references from all the plugin classes.

[image: See the kotlin directory in the screenshot]

Comment: Also add this, and this was the package ref who was declared in top of class

Comment: great. it worked

Comment: Any details why so happens?